# Javascript join/split alternative syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I used JS for quite some time now, but it seems it will never cease to amaze (and/or horrify) me.

I just stumbled upon an alternative syntax for `String.split()` / `String.join()`, where instead of calling it like a normal human being, i.e.:

```js
const s = "abc-def-ghi"
const splitted = s.split("-")     // ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
const joined = splitted.join("/") // "abc/def/ghi"
```

You do it like that:

```js
const splitted = s.split`-`     // ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
const joined = splitted.join`/` // "abc/def/ghi"
```

So my question is - ?!?!??!?!!
I didn't find any documentation on this, but it seems to work in Node 8.1+ at least. I don't know if this is something node-specific or some obscure ES syntax, but I would like to know if there's more to it and if it works with other methods.

Comment: That behaves like tagged template strings.

Comment: Those are called ES6 Literals i guess. Not sure though.

Comment: These are called 'tagged template literals', see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info

Comment: It doesn't need node, it also works on Chrome (at least)

Comment: @CerebralFart yes, thank you! That's what I was looking for. I was well aware of the string interpolation using the backtick syntax, but this is the first I've heard about the full potential of these template literals.

Comment: You should not use tagged template literals on functions/methods that are not specifically written to handle them correctly. For example this breaks ``var sep='-'; s.split`${sep}` `` while ``var sep='-'; s.split(`${sep}`)`` works as you would expect.

Comment: @str: No, of course, this is not something I would like to do, for exactly the reasons you mentioned. I was just curious how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is using [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) in a hackish way to apply the string parameter to split/join.

The signature of a tagged template function is:

```
function tag(strings: String[], ...any)
```

When you call `Array.split()` or `Array.join()` they receive an array of one string: `['-']` or `['/']`. The functions expect a string, so the array's toString() method is called, which produces a string, and used a the parameter for the split/join.

Example:

```js
function tag(strs) {
  console.log(strs.toString())
}

tag`-`
```

Answer (score 1):

When es6 was introduced it also introduced ***tagged template literals***. Where a string value runs through a prefixed function.

So, in your case it is

```
const splitted = s.split`-`     // ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
const joined = splitted.join`/` // "abc/def/ghi"
```

`split/join` works as a function which takes the template string literals and processes it.

---

Take a sample demo:

```js
function stronger(str){
    return `<strong>${str}</strong>`;
}

let str = stronger`Let's get stronger.`;

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```